# Using Redhat Developer subscription for creating openshift cluster

Tags: openshift, redhat

I have RedHat Developer Subscription For Individual users in my active subscriptions I had already bought that one. But I don't know how to use it while creating a new OpenShift Container Platform cluster. I was only able to create 60 day trial cluster. How can I use the developer subscription while creating the new cluster. If anyone know please help with this one.

Answer (score 0):

RedHat has launched Openshift Developer Sandbox. You can try and deploy applications on this sandbox for free.

You can signup and Start using immediately: https://developers.redhat.com/developer-sandbox/get-started

RedHat Developer Subscription For Individual users is focused on providing no-cost RHEL to customers.